# How to make a Django passthrough view?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I want to make a Django view that does the following:

- Receive an `HttpRequest` on `api/some/url/or/other`
- Passes this through to another server at `some/url/or/other` (rewrite the URL, basically)

  - Adding a cookie based on session data in Django
  - Using the same method, data, params, et al, that were in the original request
- Returns verbatim the response to the API call

  - Must store the cookies that came back from the call in the session
  - Must include the Django session cookie in the returned `HttpResponse`

What tools already exist in Django to do this?

Answer (score 1):

None.

You'll have to code your own wrapper utility, using one of `httplib` / `urllib` / `urllib2` libs to connect to the other server.
Most likely you will have to extract all the relevant info from the `HttpRequest` object and use that to manually construct your own request in said util function.

Regarding receiving the response from that other server, it will depend a little bit on wether you need that response only asynchronously or quasi-synchronously.